# why html input onBlur event raised when Alt key pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I find out that html input onBlur event rised every time I press Alt key.
Does anyone know why, and how to prevent it?

UPD:

I use this simle page to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var init = function(){

    var element = document.querySelector("#InputID");

    element.onkeyup = function(e){
       var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
       if(key==18) {
          console.log('alt')
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    };

    element.onblur = function(e){
       console.log('blur')
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <input type="text" id="InputID">
</body>
</html>
```

If I press Alt log looks like this (even if I change onkeyup to onkeydown):

'blur'

'alt'

Comment: @PatrickEvans - I don't say this too often but this should be an answer rather than a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows systems, the window interprets hitting the `alt` key as wanting to open the window's menu, and gives that the current input effectively bluring your input

You can use `preventDefault` to prevent this action.

```
var element = document.querySelector("#InputID");
element.onkeyup = function(e){
   var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(key===18) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
};
```

18 is the keycode for `alt`

though it seems on IE it still triggers a blur

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't work for me :(. Looks like blur triggered before keyup and even keydown events

Comment: @user2753903, what browser are you using?

Comment: I use chrome, but this happens in firefox, too. In opera blur do not triggered.

Comment: @user2753903 works in chrome and firefox for me. Edit your question to show how you are using the code.

Comment: @user2753903 can't seem to reproduce it not working in chrome or firefox, even when using the exact code you show in the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I find out that this problem caused by Ubuntu's HUD that bind to Alt. When I change locale by pressing Alt+Shift HUD doesn't shown, but still makes active window loose focus. If I rebind HUD to other key problem disapears.